# Drupal 7 - .htaccess prepend the domain when sites/default/files is used

Tags: .htaccess, drupal, dns, drupal-7

I have been asked to update Drupal's .htaccess file to create a rewrite so that all images/files are prepended with the domain.

e.g
/sites/default/files
becomes
/sites/default/files

I have never even messed with the .htaccess file before so unfortunately I don't even know where I need to start.

I would really appreciate it if someone could show me how this can be achieved, and if you could be so kind, explain what it all means so I can start to understand this stuff for next time

Answer (score 0):

.htaccess can detect and redirect path A to path B. You should define the rule(s) how redirection(s) should be detected and  made. It's not programming language so you don't have `if/then` or similar commands, but instead regular expressions are used for detecting specific situation, to collect path parts and mix them to different paths. Basically it's a rule set:

when you detect this (reg exp.) ....replace it with this

[RewriteRule is redirecting to an absolute path, rather than the proper URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13595803/rewriterule-is-redirecting-to-an-absolute-path-rather-than-the-proper-url)

I.e. in that post this rule:

```
RewriteRule ^news/?$ news.php
```

means "when you detect ***path start*** (^ = starting/start) and then ***"news/"*** and then ***end*** redirect it to news.php"

Check a bit more on regular expressions. You can i.e. take some part of path A (i.e. some id or get parameter) and use it when you generate path B.

Here are some nice articles that can help you understanding better .htaccess rewrites:

https://www.sitepoint.com/apache-mod_rewrite-examples/

https://www.addedbytes.com/articles/for-beginners/url-rewriting-for-beginners/

https://gist.github.com/ScottPhillips/1721489